# Can I use an NSDictionaryController for a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, cocoa-bindings

I have a plist file that holds information I need to display in an app organised as a dictionary of dictionaries.  I've just started programming Cocoa so am not sure the best way to go about this.  Obviously I can do it all manually, and code up the loops and add the data to the UI elements, but it seems to me that bindings and the provided controllers should let me do this more easily.

I was specifically wondering if there was a direct way (e.g. using mostly Interface Builder) to link the `NSDictionary` I get from reading the plist file, that itself contains further `NSDictionary` elements, which in turn contain name-value string pairs, to an appropriate user interface element -- probably an outline view or a browser.

Alternatively, the data would fit into a function browser type panel (like in Excel) where the top level keys are categories of functions, the next level are functions in that category, and I can just populate a text area with the lowest-level details -- i.e. the value data from the final dictionary.

Comment: Have you looked at NSDictionaryController?

Comment: I ended up loading the dictionary data from the plist into custom objects and doing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to do this with an NSBrowser or NSOutlineView.  The reason I say that is because if you are using bindings with those views you need to use an NSTreeController.  NSTreeController provides the ability to specify which keys in your model indicate whether or not the current object has children objects (isLeaf) and how to access the children objects (children).

So if you are going to use one of those two views, you must be able to add additional keys and properties to your model to do so.  Many times when I work with NSOutlineView and NSBrowser I find it easiest to skip bindings altogether and just use the all delegate & datasource methods.  They require more code but they aren't hard to put together and sometimes I prefer them to bindings if my data model is complex or if the data is not in a format that is easily pumped through an NSTreeController.

However you could use an NSTableView by doing the following.

1. Create an NSDictionaryController in your NIB.
2. In the controller that reads in your plist, create an outlet for the NSDictionaryController and hookup the outlet using Interface Builder.
3. In the code that reads the plist, add an additional line of code that set's the NSDictionaryController's content to the root dictionary from the plist.
4. In your NIB, create an NSArrayController.  Bind the array controller's "Content Array" binding to the NSDictionaryController.  For the "Controller Key" binding property, specify "arrangedObjects".
5. Now take an NSTableView and place it in your NIB.  Bind each of the NSTableColumn's "Value" bindings to the NSArrayController and for the "Controller Key" binding property, specify the key from the dictionary whose value you want to display in the table column.